# R sqldf Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "s": syntax error

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Can't use the sqldf function at all, not even the example provided by the documentation.

I've tried to change the only "s" in the argument such as:

```
sqldf("aselect * from warpbreaks limit 6")
```

the traceback was still as above.

Also tried to update the R version to the 3.6, not helpful.

```
library(sqldf)

a1r <- head(warpbreaks)
a1s <- sqldf("select * from warpbreaks limit 6")
```

Above is an example of the sqldf help document, but still not work.

Here's the traceback:

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "s": syntax error
>   16.
>   stop(structure(list(message = "near \"s\": syntax error", call =   result_create(conn@ptr, statement), cppstack = structure(list(file = "", line = -1L, stack = "C++ stack not available on this system"), class = "Rcpp_stack_trace")), class = c("Rcpp::exception", "C++Error", "error", "condition")))
>   15.
>   result_create(conn@ptr, statement)
>   14.
>   initialize(value, ...)
>   13.
>   initialize(value, ...)
>   12.
>   new("SQLiteResult", sql = statement, ptr = result_create(conn@ptr, statement), conn = conn, bigint = conn@bigint)
>   11.
>   .local(conn, statement, ...)
>   10.
>   dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
>   9.
>   dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
>   8.
>   .local(conn, statement, ...)
>   7.
>   dbGetQuery(db, sprintf("SELECT load_extension('%s')", lib_path))
>   6.
>   dbGetQuery(db, sprintf("SELECT load_extension('%s')", lib_path))
>   5.
>   initExtension(con)
>   4.
>   .local(drv, ...)
>   3.
>   dbConnect(m, dbname = dbname)
>   2.
>   dbConnect(m, dbname = dbname)
>   1.
>   sqldf("select * from warpbreaks limit 6")
>
> ### Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error, the posted code works as expected. `identical(a1r, a1s)` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: The first code block uses `aselect` which is invalid keyword. The second one works for me.